# Validating checkboxes from form in Django

Tags: python, django, validation, checkbox

Relatively new to Python..

I would like to know how to check if a check box has been selected.
I am reading the form values into a python script and am unsure how to go about validating.

Using the Web Framework Django.  The form is being posted back to a views.py script.
I am loading up a dictionary with many different variables. These variables need to then be passed to a shell script, the command to the shell script requires these check box values to be returned in the form of 0 or 1 in order to create a zip file.

I understand this code is not python but it is my understanding of what i am trying to achieve:

```
if variable.checked == 'yes'
    return 1
elif
    return 0
```

Comment: Are you using some kind of web framework here, like Django? How is the form being submitted to Python? A bit of background would be useful.

Comment: This is not Python code.

Comment: Sorry, its using django framework which i also have little to no experience with.

Comment: the form is being posted back to a views.py script

Comment: I am loading up a dictionary with the variables.  These variables need to then be passed to a shell script in the form of 0 or 1 in order to create a zipfile. Hopefully this is more use.

Comment: i understand that i did not provide python code, but its my understanding of what i am trying to achieve only in python.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the Django docs on processing form data: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#processing-the-data-from-a-form

Comment: @smurf you should edit your question with the extran info instead of adding it as comments. It's easier for people to give you an anwser when they can read all the relevant information in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/) is really quite good.  Check out the [description of the HttpRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) class for more information on how this part works.  The short answer is that you can do something like this:

```
def myview(request):
    # do stuff
    option_checked = 'myvariable.checkboxoption' in request.REQUEST
    # do more stuff and return the response
```

That being said, Django also has a comprehensive [form widget/validation/extraction subsystem](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/).  I'd recommend going through the full [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/) (particularly part 4, which covers forms) and checking out the mailing list to answer any more specific questions about how to use these libraries.

Comment: This code doesn't follow Python "idioms". The content of the function should be `option_checked = 'myvariable.checkboxoption' in request.REQUEST`